# why is to_numeric() converting str to float instead of int?

Tags: python, pandas

Noob here.

I have a pandas dataframe, and I'm trying to convert a column of numbers from a string type to an integer. But when I use to_numeric(), it converts to a float instead.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

```
citydata.tcad_id
```

results in

```
0      0206180115

2      0125050304

3      0225050137

4      0124000601

         ...    
995    0250300107

996    0217230301

997    0203030703

998    0135070323

999    0204160717

Name: tcad_id, Length: 1000, dtype: object
```

And

```
type(citydata.tcad_id[0])
```

shows the first (and subsequent) entries are...

```
str
```

So I tried

```
pd.to_numeric(citydata.tcad_id, downcast='integer', errors='coerce')
```

But that results in

```
0      206180115.0

1      419120319.0

2      125050304.0

3      225050137.0

4      124000601.0

       ...     

995    250300107.0

996    217230301.0

997    203030703.0

998    135070323.0

999    204160717.0

Name: tcad_id, Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

I need them to be integers so I can compare against another list of integers.

HALP!

Comment: See the note at the end of the parameters block in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). Simply cast to int after you're done with `.astype(int)`.

Comment: Is there `nan` in your column?

Comment: _I need them to be integers so I can compare against another list of integers._ That shouldn’t be an issue though.

Comment: Yes, there is 'Nan' in the column.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) you'll see the following:

`The default return dtype is float64 or int64 depending on the data supplied. Use the downcast parameter to obtain other dtypes.`

So it seems like pandas has decided to cast your data into `float64`. Use `downcast:'integer'` to get integer values.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing with pd.to_numeric(citydata.tcad_id, downcast='integer', errors='coerce') as described in the post? Is there an additional step required to downcast?

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but are there "nan" or infinites in your data? This was the issue in my case. You can try doing:

```py
pd.to_numeric(citydata.tcad_id.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(), 
downcast='integer', errors='coerce')
```